# Почему показывает только 3 страницы?

Tags: pagination, php, wordpress

```
$new_query->query('cat=' . $idcat .  '&paged=&post_type=post&posts_per_page=2');
global $counter_blog;
$counter_blog = 1;
while ($new_query->have_posts()) :
  $new_query->the_post();
  $times = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'timenews', true);
$times = strtotime($times);
if( $fromdate<=$times && $todate >= $times)
    {
        get_template_part( 'content-calendar', get_post_format() );
    }
    $counter_blog++;    
endwhile;

   previous_posts_link();
echo "\t\t";
 next_posts_link();
```

Вот есть такой код, почему показывает только 3 страницы максимум? Не могу понять, где это поменять, причем если выводить по 1-й записи на странице, так же 3 страницы всего заполнены?

------update------

Переделал вывод вот так, теперь ссылки пагинации отображают реальное количество страниц (до этого показывало 3), но все после третьей пустые...

```
 query_posts(array('cat'=>$idcat,'posts_per_page'=>1, 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) ));
    if ( have_posts() ) :

            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                get_template_part( 'content-calendar', get_post_format() ); 
            endwhile; 
                endif;  
    echo paginate_links();
```

Но лучше первый вариант, т.к. там нормально работает фильтрация по дате, а во втором не нормально. :)

Comment: Выведите print_r($wp_query) и посмотрите какой запрос SQL у вас создается. Также присмотритесь к функции paginate_links(), согласно документации туда должен передаваться массив опций, в том числе номер текущей страницы и общее количество страниц.

Comment: Я добавил больше записей и во втором случае, страницы добавляются, пагинация показывает нужное количество страниц, но контретно последние 2 страницы пустые идут.   [max_num_pages] => 7  все правильно, как и должно быть...

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не используйте `query_posts()` если вы новичок и не знаете что делает хук. Просто лучше забудьте о нем, тем более без `wp_reset_postdata()` в конце. Используйте или `get_posts()` или `new WP_Query`.

Далее, из куска кода не понятно, откуда Вы берете `$idcat` и зачем Вам

`global $counter_blog;
 $counter_blog = 1;`

И как вам нужно отсортировать записи?

Адекватно и правильно переписать последний UPD на:

```
$args = [
        'cat' => $idcat,
        'posts_per_page'=>1,
        'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') )  ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
];
$list = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $list->have_posts() ) : while ( $list->have_posts() ) : $list->the_post();
        /* Тут выполняем нужные действия с постом или подключаем нужную часть темплейта */
    endwhile;
    echo paginate_links();
endif;
```

Дополнительно указываем что нам делать с функцией пагинации(как выводить ссылки или список страниц), так как `paginate_links()` возвращает массив.

Пояснения для аргументов и прочего:

`$idcat` - ID категории, с которой нужно выводить посты.

`posts_per_page` - количество постов вывода на страницу за раз

`paged` - определение текущей страница пагинации

Также, в первом куске кода, при создании вопроса, есть сортировка по метаполю связанным с временем, её можно выполнить сразу в массиве параметров `$args` и не создавать дополнительных циклов. В таком случае, у Вас сразу будет отсортированный список запрашиваемых постов. В коде, что я предоставил как пример, сортировка по-умолчинию будет предоставлена по дате добавления поста.